# In closing Angular dialog create a transition

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, dialog

I have created an animation when the dialog is opening but I want the same when the Angular dialog is closing.

This is my code for opening dialog with animation:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="body-container" [ngClass]="getBorderColor()">
</div>
 <button mat-dialog-close>Cancel</button>
</div>

.body-container {
  animation: animation-name .5s ease-out forwards;
}

@keyframes animation-name {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(100%);  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}
```

And here is the stackblitz I have created.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/slow-dialog-f5nnnr?file=app%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.css

Comment: can you show your code in stackblitz(put code fork it and post link)

Comment: @לבנימלכה I will try to create

Comment: @לבנימלכה I have created the stackblitz